# Elasticsearch - aggregation and counting elements from array

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm learning Elasticsearch and I have a problem with aggregating and counting elements. Let's say we have our data like this:

```
{
  "sessionId": "session1",
  "messages": [
    { "intent": "intentX", "message": "foo1" },
    { "intent": "intentY", "message": "foo2" },
    { "intent": "intentY", "message": "foo3" },
    { "intent": "intentZ", "message": "foo4" }
  ]
},
{
  "sessionId": "session2",
  "messages": [
    { "intent": "intentX", "message": "foo5" },
    { "intent": "intentY", "message": "foo6" },
    { "intent": "intentY", "message": "foo7" },
    { "intent": "intentY", "message": "foo8" }
  ]
}
```

How can I count how many times each intent occurred? I've tried the query as follows but seems like it returns invalid values - not sure how is it counted now. All mappings are default.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "intents": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "messages.intent.keyword"
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "count" : { 
          "value_count" : { 
            "field" : "messages.intent.keyword" 
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result for the query:

```
{
   "took":2,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":1,
      "successful":1,
      "skipped":0,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":{
         "value":2,
         "relation":"eq"
      },
      "max_score":null,
      "hits":[
         
      ]
   },
   "aggregations":{
      "intents":{
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
         "sum_other_doc_count":0,
         "buckets":[
            {
               "key":"intentX",
               "doc_count":2,
               "count":{
                  "value":5
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"intentY",
               "doc_count":2,
               "count":{
                  "value":5
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"intentZ",
               "doc_count":1,
               "count":{
                  "value":3
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

The result I want to have is intentX.count.value = 2, intentY.count.value = 5 and intentZ.count.value = 1, so sum of intents from every array including duplicates.

Thanx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it - I had to set "messages" field as "nested" in mapping, and then use this query to get what I wanted:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "intents": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "messages"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "messages.intent.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gave me the desired result.